# "Like" option in News feed is missing

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

I have a news feed web part in my home page. But, for some reason the "Like" option is missing and I cant find where to put this back.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Amal, It worked!

Comment: Hi Amal, It worked! But the corret list to configure is the "Post" list

Comment: Ok cool. I have posted it as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `like` option using

1. Open View All Site Content
2. Then you can see a list with name Post
3. Now open the list and open list settings
4. Then click on Rating settings and then enable `Allow items in this list to be rated` and `Which voting/rating experience you would like to enable for this list?`